# BULK INSERT ISSUE picking up funny character on first line

Tags: t-sql, bulkinsert

Referring to this article [Bulk Insert Includes Line Terminator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312096/bulk-insert-includes-line-terminator/16320907#16320907) is there now a resolution for it as I was attempting the same problem and get the same issue. I saved my file in NotePad as Unicode as suggested and made no difference. Here is the first data value: ´╗┐Abe

Code:

```
BULK
INSERT BulkWordInsert
FROM '<sometextfile>.txt'
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ':',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

Comment: Does adding a codepage help? `WITH (CODEPAGE = 'RAW')`

Comment: Yeah I have tried this variation and DATAFILETYPE='char' does not work, and DATAFILETYPE='widechar' and also using CODEPAGE='65001'. All variations make no difference. The only way I see is after the bulk insert I have to fix it by writing SQL that trims off this funny text

Comment: Those characters are the byte mark for UTF-8, which is not supported by SQL Server. You should convert the input file to UTF-16. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137558/how-to-handle-import-of-file-with-utf-8-encoding-codepage-65001-into-sql-ser

Answer (score 0):

I recommend opening the file using a super-dooper text editor such as UltraEdit (download free trial at ultraedit.com), then hit Ctrl-H to go into Hex mode, and eyeball whether you are loading that character with BULK INSERT because that character is actually in the file.   Guessing other text editors would be able to do this, but UltraEdit is the one I'm most familiar with.

If so, then you'll have to contact the source of the file and ask them to remove it, or load it and then write T-SQL to REPLACE(the_string, the_goofy_character, '').

I had this problem with a previous client where a UNIX mainframe kicked out text files that had odd characters.